# Adding to the beginning of a line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html that has the tag `<ins>...</ins>` at various places. I would like to be able to add something to the beginning of whichever line has those tags. When I say "line" I mean that there are `<br>` tags (not `<br/>` tags) as well.

Here's some (made up) html:

```
It was a very nice day in my home town.<br>
Then suddenly a <ins>dragon</ins> came!<br>
This <ins>dragon</ins> was absolutely <ins>terrifying</ins>,<br>
and he made everyone flee. The end.
```

I have tried several things. Line 2 is the closest, but I should probably use something like line 3, but it's not doing the trick.

```
$("ins").each(function() {
 $(this).prev().after("&rarr; "); // this almost works, but inserts an extra → in line 3
 $(this).closest("br").after("&rarr; "); // not sure why this doesn't work
});
```

The result should look like this:

```
It was a very nice day in my home town.
→ Then suddenly a <ins>dragon</ins> came!
→ This <ins>dragon</ins> was absolutely <ins>terrifying</ins>,
and he made everyone flee. The end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify selector inside [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to avoid selecting any other tag. The [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is using to get closest ancestor element and not the sibling.

```js
$("ins").each(function() {
  $(this).prev('br').after("&rarr; ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
It was a very nice day in my home town.
<br>Then suddenly a <ins>dragon</ins> came!
<br>This <ins>dragon</ins> was absolutely <ins>terrifying</ins>,
<br>and he made everyone flee.
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't realize you can add an element name to prev(). That worked perfectly, thanks. I'll mark it as the answer in a minute.